# List comprehension iterating over two lists is not working as expected

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension

I want to iterate over two lists. The first list contains some browser user-agents and the second list contains versions of those browsers. I want to filter out only those user-agents whose version is greater than 60.

Here is how my list comprehension looks:

```
[link for ver in version for link in useragents if ver > 60]
```

The problem with this list is that it prints same user-agent multiple times. I wrote the following using the `zip` function, which works fine:

```
for link, ver in zip(useragents, version):
    if ver > 60:
        # append to list
        print(link)
```

Why is my list comprehension returning unexpected results?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your first list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
res = []
for ver in version:
    for link in useragents:
        if ver > 60:
            res.append(link)
```

Notice you have nested loop with time complexity O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), i.e. you are iterating over *every combination* of `version` and `useragents`. That's not what you want, assuming your `version` and `useragents` lists are aligned.

The equivalent of your `for` loop is the following list comprehension:

```
res = [link for link, ver in zip(useragents, version) if ver > 60]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
[link for (link, ver) in zip(useragents, version) if ver > 60]
```

You still have to zip the two lists together.

Answer (score 8):

This

```
[link for ver in version for link in useragents if ver > 60]
```

is not the same as zip. It's not iterating through the two sequences in parallel. It's iterating through all combinations of those two sequences.

It is as if you wrote:

```
for ver in version:
    for link in useragents:
        if ver > 60:
            # append(link)
```

So if both sequences had length 5, there would be 25 combinations (some of which are filtered out by the condition `ver > 60`).

When you want to go through sequences in parallel, `zip` is the way to do it, even in a comprehension.

```
[link for (link, ver) in zip(useragents, version) if ver > 60]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the function [`compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) in combination with  `map()`, where you check some condition:

```
from itertools import compress

filter_ = map(lambda x: x > 60, version)
list(compress(useragents, filter_))
```

#### Example:

```
s = 'ABCDEFG'
nums = range(len(s))
    
filter_ = map(lambda x: x > 3, nums)
print(list(compress(s, filter_)))
# ['E', 'F', 'G']
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure on what's happening, without your data, but in general, "double" list comprehension is not the same as `zip`, but rather a double loop, i.e.

```
[a for b in bs for a in as]
```

is equivalent to

```
for b in bs:
    for a in as:
        lst.append(a)
```